# Iterating over Linq-to-Entities IEnumerable causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The part of the code I'm working on receives an

```
IEnumerable<T> items
```

where each item contains a class with properties reflecting a MSSQL database table.

The database table has a total count of 953664 rows.
The dataset in code is filtered down to a set of 284360 rows.

The following code throws an OutOfMemoryException when the process reaches about 1,5 GB memory allocation.

```
 private static void Save<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, IList<IDataWriter> dataWriters, IEnumerable<PropertyColumn> columns) where T : MyTableClass
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
        }
    }
```

The variable **items** is of type

```
IQueryable<MyTableClass>
```

I can't find anyone with the same setup, and other's solutions that I've found doesn't apply here.

I've also tried paging, using Skip and Take with a page size of 500, but that just takes a long time and ends up with the same result. It seems like objects aren't being released after each iteration. How is that?

How can I rewrite this code to cope with a larger collection set?

Comment: You should *absolutely* be paginating the data if you have that many items to work on.  We couldn't possibly tell you how you're still holding onto references to the object in *code that you haven't even provided*.

Comment: @Servy What exactly are you missing? The items variable is an IQueryable, so doing e.g. items.count() will put the entire query into memory.

Comment: If you're paginating it then it won't, no.  You should be able to provide an an example capable of replicating the problem whereby you paginate a query and show that the items aren't being reclaimed once you've finished with a given page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Servy has already said you didn't provide your code so I'll try to make some predictions... (Sorry for my english)

If you have an exception in "foreach (var item in items)" when you are using paging then, I guess, something wrong with paging. I wrote a couple of examples to explain my idea.

if first example I suggest you (just for test) put your filter inside the Save function.

```
private static void Save<T>(IQueryable<T> items, IList<IDataWriter> dataWriters, IEnumerable<PropertyColumn> columns) where T : MyTableClass
{
    int pageSize = 500; //Only 500 records will be loaded.
    int currentStep = 0;
    while (true)
    {
         //Here we create a new request into the database using our filter.                
         var tempList = items.Where(yourFilter).Skip(currentStep * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
         foreach (var item in tempList)
         {
            //If you have an exception here maybe something wrong in your dataWriters or columns.
         }
         currentStep++;
         if (tempList.Count() == 0) //No records have been loaded so we can leave.
             break;
    }
}
```

The second example show how to use paging without any changes in the Save function

```
int pageSize = 500;
int currentStep = 0;
while (true)
{
    //Here we create a new request into the database using our filter.                
    var tempList = items.Where(yourFilter).Skip(currentStep * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    Save(tempList, dataWriters, columns); //Calling saving function.
    currentStep++;
    if (tempList.Count() == 0)
        break;
}
```

Try both of them and you'll either resolve your problem or find another place where an exception is raised.

By the way, another potential place is your dataWriters. I guess there you store all data that your have been received from the database. Maybe you shouldn't save all data? Just calculate memory size that all objects are required.

P.S. And don't use while(true) in your code. It just an example:)

Comment: Thanks for providing examples. In regards of the paging code, my code is the same as yours, though I didn't add the filters here. I found out that EF is keeping the data in memory for change tracking, and since we are currently using .NET 3.5 we don't have the possibility to turn off tracking using AsNoTracking().